# Android 11 (SDK 30) custom file picker library

Tags: android, scoped-storage

I was working on select file from file picker in Android.

In **SDK 29**, I was able to work with custom file picker such as https://github.com/DroidNinja/Android-FilePicker and https://github.com/AnilFurkanOkcun/UWMediaPicker-Android. However, they seem not support for **SDK 30 (Android 11)**. I have no choice but to use default file picker.

The problem is, default file picker *not support* for `limit for maximum number of file selected` and `max file size selected`.

My question is, is there any good custom file picker library now available for **SDK 30**?

Comment: You did not tell the reason those file pickers do not work on 30.

Comment: Quote from first link: `This Filepicker is based on the MediaStore api provided by android. It checks MediaStore database for a file entry. If your file is not showing in the picker, it means that it is not inserted into MediaStore database yet.`. Aha.. That is no classic file picker and worse it uses the .DATA column and getrealpathfromuri.

Comment: The reason is because of the original author didn't support for these features. and I had forced to do it by my own.

Comment: Wrong. I just told you the reason why the first one does not work.

Comment: Meaning that, currently all the 3rd party library are the same?

Comment: Dont know. If they use getrealpathfromuri then yes. But a file picker should not use that stuff.

Comment: I think the solution will be if you are accessing all the file, you must use system picker instead of any of the 3rd party library.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Simple Storage](https://github.com/anggrayudi/SimpleStorage)'s file picker. It supports scoped storage.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val storageHelper = SimpleStorageHelper(this)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        storageHelper.onFolderSelected = { requestCode, folder ->
            // do stuff
        }
        storageHelper.onFileSelected = { requestCode, file ->
            // do stuff
        }

        btnOpenFolderPicker.setOnClickListener { storageHelper.openFolderPicker() }
        btnOpenFilePicker.setOnClickListener { storageHelper.openFilePicker() }
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        storageHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        storageHelper.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```